# Luracast Restler JSON format validation

Tags: php, api, rest

I am wondering if Restler handle validation on JSON request format?

In example, I have this JSON request:

```
{ "id" : 1, "party_id" : , "description" : "say it here" }
```

The value for party_id should invalid. Any insights? Thanks.

Comment: Currently **Restler** will just get `NULL` when it comes across malformed JSON. I will update it to throw an Error with meaningful explanation

Comment: Thanks for that, looking forward to that update. By the way any suggestions on how to at least have basic validation for malformed JSON for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### JSON Validation in Restler 2.0.5

Starting from **Restler** version 2.0.5, restler automatically throws HTTP 400 status with a meaningful error message when the JSON body in the request is malformed.

for example

```
curl -X POST http://restler2.dev/examples/_006_crud/index.php/author -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name": "Another", "email": "another@email.com'
```

returns

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Bad Request: Error parsing JSON, malformed JSON"
  }
}
```

It requires PHP 5.3 and above

## Update

Restler 2.0.6 adds error support for older versions of PHP 5

So [help.luracast.com/restler/examples](http://help.luracast.com/restler/examples) which is using PHP 5.2.17 will return the following response for cURL

```
curl -X POST http://help.luracast.com/restler/examples/_006_crud/index.php/authr -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name": "Another", "email": "another@email.com",}'

{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Bad Request: Error parsing JSON"
  }
}
```